# ggplot2: solid line for one group, points for the other

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have four series that I would like to plot.
There are 2 models : xg and algo30.
There are two types of data: predicted and observed.
This means we have the following 4 series: "predicted xg","observed xg", "predicted 30", "observed 30".

I want  "xg" to be blue, "algo30" to be red.
I also want predicted to be a solid line and observed to be points.

Here is what I mean, using base plot:

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
gr <- 1:10
obs.xg <- sort(runif(10, 0.5, 1))
obs.30 <- sort(runif(10, 0.5, 1))
pred.xg <- lm(obs.xg~gr) %>% predict() %>% add(rnorm(10,0,.01))
pred.30 <- lm(obs.30~gr) %>% predict() %>% add(rnorm(10,0,.01))        
plot(gr, obs.xg, col="darkblue", ylim=range(c(obs.xg,obs.30)), pch=20)
lines(gr, pred.xg, col="darkblue", lwd=2)
points(gr, obs.30, col="firebrick", pch=20)
lines(gr, pred.30, col="firebrick", lwd=2)
legend("bottomright", 
  pch=c(20,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  lty=c(NA,1,NA,1,1),
  lwd=c(NA,1,NA,2,2),
  col = c("black","black",NA, "darkblue","firebrick"),
  legend=c("observé","prédit",NA,"xgboost","algo30"),
  bty='n')
```

[image]

Here is my best attempt using ggplot.  Notice that the legend doesnt work as I want.

```
xg.data <- data.frame(model= "xg", decile = seq(1:10), observed = obs.xg, predicted = pred.xg)
algo30.data <- data.frame(model = "algo30",decile = seq(1:10),  observed = obs.30, predicted = pred.30)
ggplotdata <- bind_rows(xg.data, algo30.data)

ggplotdata %>%
   ggplot( aes(x=decile, y= predicted, color= model))+ geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(x=decile, y= observed, color = model))
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to include your packages as part of the question (I have no idea where `add()` comes).

Comment: my bad - I lost the first line  when copy pasting.   it's magrittr::add

Comment: What's wrong with base R? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time when making a legend like this I look to `override.aes` in `guide_legend()`.

The idea here is to make a legend using an additional aesthetic that you don't want mapped onto the plot itself and then using constants instead of a variable for that aesthetic.  I used `alpha`, since both points and lines use that aesthetic.

Then the heavy lifting is done in `scale_alpha_manual`: removing the legend name, making sure the plot still looks right by setting the `values`, and then, finally, picking the correct point type and lines along with blanks for the legend.

```
ggplot(ggplotdata, aes(x=decile, y= predicted, color= model))+ 
    geom_line( aes(alpha = "prédit") )+
    geom_point(aes(x=decile, y= observed, alpha = "observé")) +
    scale_alpha_manual(name = NULL, values = c(1, 1),
                       guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(0, 1), shape = c(16, NA)))) +
    scale_color_manual(name = NULL, values = c("firebrick", "darkblue"))
```

[image]

Comment: I wasnt aware of override.aes , this is exactly what I needed, thanks!   I'll move the goalpost a bit and add a quick note on how to remove the point from the color legend here:   +  scale_color_manual(name = NULL,
                     values = c("firebrick", "darkblue"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes= list(shape = c(NA, NA)))) # no point please